# Remove the datetime string from each row in a Dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
   Film      Description       
0  Batman    Viewed in 2021-10-04T14:30:31Z City Hall, London
1  Superman  Aired 2012-01-04R11:01:10Z in the USA first
2  Hulk      2010-07-04S07:22:02Z Still being produced
```

I want to remove the date-time from each row in the 'Description' column, to look like this:

```
    Film      Description      
0   Batman    Viewed in City Hall, London
1   Superman  Aired in the USA first
2   Hulk      Still being produced
```

I have attempted this string regex:

```
df['Description'] = df['Description '].str.replace(r'\^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})Z', '')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\^` matches a caret symbol.

Other than `T`, I see `R` and `S` in the datetime stamps, they must be added.

Use

```py
\s*\b\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}[TRS]\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}Z\b
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/l1r15f/1/).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{4}                    digits (0-9) (4 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{2}                    digits (0-9) (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{2}                    digits (0-9) (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [TRS]                    any character of: 'T', 'R', 'S'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{2}                    digits (0-9) (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{2}                    digits (0-9) (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{2}                    digits (0-9) (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Z                        'Z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
```

Comment: does this remove the datatime regardless of where it is in the string (i.e in the beginning, middle, end, etc) ?

Comment: @user341383 Yes.

Answer (score 1):

i haven't gone as far as replicating your dataframe, but you regex is not going to work with the carrot ^ will lock the match to the beginning of the string, and you have a 'T' in there, which will only match on one of those description.

try:

```html
(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}[TSR]\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})Z
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.replace` to replace;

Any non white space before `:` OR Any non white after `:` OR `:` itself.

```
    df['Description']=df['Description'].str.replace('\S+(?=[:])|(?<=[:])\S+|[:]','')
print(df)



       Film             Description
0    Batman  Viewed in  City Hall, London
1  Superman       Aired  in the USA first
2      Hulk          Still being produced
```